# How to send localized email from console shell file in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, localization, console

I need to send an email with localized body from the console shell in cakephp.
I used __d () to localize the message, but it didn't work (in console shell). Is there any other way to make it work. I also tried with $this->out(__d()). but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the reason is the right locale is not set to the script.

Either you set your locale via command line, for example:

```
cake myscript --lang deu
```

Or if each email has a different language you'll need to change it on the fly.

Comment: To burzum, localize files is located located at the correct location, it works for other location very well. But when I used __d() localization in /Console/Command/XyzShell.php file (cakephp console) to send an email, it won't work. I just get msgid rather localize string.